# laravel Model Relations result

Tags: laravel, collections, model

`admin_roles` and `admin_permissions` table is a many-to-many relationship

Query ID from `admin_permission` where `admin_roles` ID in 1,2

Use SQL implementation:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT`admin_role_permissions`.permission_id
FROM
    `admin_permissions`
INNER JOIN `admin_role_permissions` ON `admin_permissions`.`id` = 
    `admin_role_permissions`.`permission_id`
WHERE
   `admin_role_permissions`.`role_id` IN (1, 2)
```

The result:

> $permission_ids = [1,3,4....];

How to use laravel model to the above effect?

#### AdminRoleController.php

```
$role_ids = ['1','2'];
$permissions = AdminRole::with('relPermission')->whereIn('id', $role_ids)->get();
```

#### AdminRole.php

```
public function relPermission(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\AdminPermission', 'admin_role_permissions', 'role_id', 'permission_id');
}
```

But the result:

[image]

How can I obtain a result like

> $permission_ids=[1,3,4.....]

use laravel model or laravel collection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pluck method :

```
$permissions = AdminRole::with('relPermission')->whereIn('id', $role_ids)->pluck('rel_permission.id');
```